# Inject text with ::after only for a specific class

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have the following HTML

```
<style>
p::after { 
    content: "%";
}
</style>

<div class="counter-box">
    <p data-value="185">100</p>
</div>
```

The current CSS I have now injects text for all paragraphs.
I need to inject text in

element with counter-box class only.

Answer (score 0):

Super simple. Just use this CSS code instead:

```
.counter-box p::after { 
    content: "%";
}
```

The code above injects text into all p paragraphs that are inside the .counter-box class only.

For more information on selectors, click here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp